# How acurate are depictions of reservation life in the Disney+ series Reservation Dogs?

Tags: historical-accuracy, reservation-dogs

With the obvious exception of scenes depicting the paranormal and the deliberately outlandish, does the Disney+\FX series *Reservation Dogs* show an accurate depiction of life on a Native reservation in that part of America during that time period, or is it largely a fictional construct?

For example are the depictions of hopelessness, casual crime, substance abuse, and the idiosyncrasies of it's infrastructure relatable to the people and location in which it was set, or is this the equivalent of a show like Clueless or Fresh Prince which are heavily stylized and written to play on tropes about the locations for entertainment purposes, rather than to depict them accurately

Comment: A couple points: 1) though the show is filmed in the Muscogee Nation, the name of the reservation and the tribe the characters belong to is never mentioned. 2) If you research this a little, you'll find a lot of praise from American Indian actors or filmmakers about the "accuracy" and the "representation", but I can't find any commentary any deeper than that.  If that level of detail would make for an acceptable answer, it would be pretty easy to cobble together from various entertainment journalism sources.